# Windows Server 2012 R2 loses network shared printers

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, printing

I have one Windows Server 2012 R2 virtual machine on the ESXi server. It has RDS role, so multiple users can use it at the same time. Via GPO the user account receives some basic settings like shortcuts on the desktop, printers settings and etc. Everything based on the group to which the account belongs to.

The issue is that members of **one** group lose their printer settings. The default printer or other printers for them simply disappear.
I’ve checked GPO policy settings several times, but everything looks ok for me.

Sometimes `gpupdate /force` helps to temporary solve the issue. The deletion of accounts temporary helps too.
I looks like it is a GPO issue, but for now I don’t know which options to check.

KB3159398 isn't in the list of installed updates.